# ng-repeat not printing resp.items from cloudendpoint on webpage

Tags: angularjs, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm new to angularjs. I'm working on a web application using angularjs and cloud endpoints. I'm getting the response from endpoint and I can see that in **Console.log** also. but when I'm trying to print that response it's not working. I'm not getting what's going wrong. Can anyone fix this?

Here's my code.

**HTML Page**

```
<div ng-repeat="lister in lists">
</div><h2>{{lister.title}}</h2>
</div>
```

**AngularJs Code**

```
    <script>
       function init() {
       window.init();
        }
    </script>
    <script>
       var app = angular.module('list',[]);
       app.controller('listCtrl',function($scope,$window){
          $window.init= function() {
             $scope.loader();
           };
          $scope.loader= function(){
             gapi.client.load('MyEndPoint', 'v1', function(){

             gapi.client.MyEndPoint.MyMethod1({
            'latitude':'24.5555','longitude':'45.55555'
             }).execute(function(resp) {
                $window.console.log(resp);
                $scope.lists = resp.items;
          });
           }, 'https://MyEndpointURL.appspot.com/_ah/api');
           };
    </script>
```

Comment: Make sure that div element present in controller scope.Have you used ng-controller or routing to bind template to controller scope?